# Flex row layout for text, react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I would like the text and numbers to wrap, however I also have the Number and Text wrapped in a TouchableOpacity, so I don't know how to make the text flow inline. Meaning I would like the next number to come at the end of the previous verse, not on the next line.

```js
// These are only the relevant snippets of code to help with the question 

// Verse Component
render() {
  return  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.verseContainer} onPress={() => this.props.toggleOptions()}>
                <Text style={[styles.font, styles.verseNumber]}>
                    {this.props.number}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.font}>
                    {this.props.text}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
}

// List render that renders all the verse componenets 
render() {
        var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <FlatList data={this.state.verses}
                          renderItem={v => this.renderVerse(v.item)}
                          keyExtractor={v => v.verseNumber}
                          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                          style={[styles.listContainer, {height: height - 70, width: width}]}/>
                <CommentaryCarousel/>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
listContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    height: 100,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 10,
    zIndex: -1
},
verseContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10,

},
});
```

**Current Layout:**

[image: Current Status]

Comment: Replace the React markup with the resulting HTML markup together with relevant CSS, reproducing your issue here and programmers with CSS knowledge will be able to help without needing to know React at all. To help with this issue, anyone with sufficient CSS knowledge needs to be able to inspect a live example. Please provide it.

Comment: You probably don't need a FlatList. Just wrap your list items inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by rendering each word separately. Otherwise, flex-wrap tries to wrap each , so if a sentence is too long, it doesn't fit it at the end of the next sentence.